# Test has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (org/testng/annotations/TestNG)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, cucumber

I found my issue below when using this dependencies:

```
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

the issue showing when I run the `mvn  clean test`  :

org/testng/annotations/Test has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to determine if this is specifically related to the dependencies mentioned.The error message text referenced in the question suggests that this is a Java version mismatch problem.

The Java Class File Disassembler tool can be used to inspect compiled Java class files. This can be useful for resolving `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` exceptions which may occur due to a mismatch between the version of Java used to compile a file and the current JRE version executing it.

**Potential Approach to Fix**

1. Use the `javap` command to check the version of the Java runtime used to compile the file referenced in the exception.

```
javap -v org/testng/annotations/Test
```

If you have `grep` installed you might find it easier to do something like the following.

```
javap -v org/testng/annotations/Test  | grep 'major version'
```

2. Use [this table from the Java Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2) to find the Java version which corresponds to the major version number.
3. Re-compile the files or install a compatabile JRE version to resolve.

**Related Questions**

More detailed discussions around this type of Java version compatibility issue can be found at the links below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47457105/class-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-environment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Andre ..

Finally I using another version of testNG which is version    '<version>6.14.3</version>'.